Using LCEL with Memory
I had a LLMChain which I want to change now with LCEL to have proper support for streaming.
My original chain was:
llm_chain = LLMChain(
            llm=llm_chat,
            prompt=prompt,
            output_key="answer",
            verbose=False,
        )

My updated chain is:
retrieved_chat_history = ChatMessageHistory(messages=[]) ## example
conversation_memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
            input_key="question",
            output_key="answer",
            memory_key="chat_history",
            return_messages=True,
            chat_memory=retrieved_chat_history,
        )

lcel_chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(
        chat_history=lambda x: conversation_memory.load_memory_variables(x)["chat_history"]
    )
    | prompt
    | llm_chat
    | {"answer": RunnablePassthrough()}
)

The problem with the new LCEL syntax is my history object ConversationBuffereMemory is not updated after every invocation. How can I fix this?
Apart from the snippet pasted I also tried following snippet but it does not work:

from langchain_core.runnables.history import RunnableWithMessageHistory
base_chain = prompt | llm_chat 

# Create a function to get an empty message history
def get_session_history(session_id):
    return ChatMessageHistory()

# Wrap the base chain with RunnableWithMessageHistory
chain_with_memory = RunnableWithMessageHistory(
    base_chain,
    get_session_history,
    input_messages_key="question",
    history_messages_key=memory_key,
    output_messages_key="answer"
)

session_id = "user_123"  # Use a unique identifier for each conversation
result = chain_with_memory.invoke(
    {"question": "Hello, my name is XYZ"},
    config={"configurable": {"session_id": session_id}}
)


